# Using AWS S3 access logs to track downloads

Tags: amazon-s3

We're trying to use the S3 access logs to track downloads of a file. It's fine with us if some log entries are lost. We're trying to figure out how to handle the 206 HTTP status code. Since it does not get the full file, we can't count it as a download. But we can't discount it either since it is a part of a download. Does anyone have an idea how to go about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Amazon S3 logs doesn't contain anything that will mark the completion of the file download request.

Workaround: Add random ID which is unique for a file request in the referrer header. Amazon logs referrer header in the S3 logs. Total downloads would the total of random ID for which total of bytes sent is greater than or equal to bytes sent.

Answer (score 0):

My thought is to count up the bytes shipped and then divide by the object size, which should be known.  Does anyone see a problem with this approach?

Comment: Two half files are not equal to one whole. A user might stop half way twice, but at the end have received no usable file.

Comment: Indeed, but I wasn't looking for something perfectly accurate, just mostly accurate.  My thought is that most downloads complete.  It turns out though that the HTTP 206s are much larger than the 200s.